# prevUntil() / prev() function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="add"  />        
  <input type="text" id="score1" value="0" class="score" size="1" />        
  <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />
  </td>

  <td>
  <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="add" />        
  <input type="text" id="score2" value="0" class="score" size="1" />        
  <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus"  />
  </td>

  <td><input type="button" value="enter" id="update" class="update" ></td>
 </tr>



   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $(".add").click(function()
        {
            var currentVal = parseInt($(this).next(".score").val());
            if (currentVal != NaN)
            {
                $(this).next(".score").val(currentVal + 1);
            } 
        });

        $(".minus").click(function()
        {
            var currentVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".score").val());
            if (currentVal != NaN)
            {
                $(this).prev(".score").val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

above codes are ok works as i want.
now,  i want to alert the calculated result according to user's input and here i fail. 
below code doesnt work. also i have more than 1 row (i.e. tr) so consider that i have lots of input texts and buttons. when i press one of the enter buttons i got NaN. pls help me to correct below code. thanks and regards

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.update').click(function(){ 

    var firstresult = parseInt($(this).prev("#score1").val());
    var secondresult = parseInt($(this).prev("#score2").val());

    if(firstresult < secondtresult) {
      result = '2';
    } else if(firstresult > secondtresult) {
      result ='1';
    } else if (firstresult = secondtresult) { 
      result = 'x';       
    } 

    alert(result);     
  });  
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: FYI, you can't have more than one object with the same id value.  Each id must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The id's for element should be unique in a page and considering that fact you can directly use the id selector. Also the `$(this).prev("#score1")` will not select anything because it is not a sibling of update button, same applies to `score2`. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.update').click(function(){ 

    var firstresult = parseInt($("#score1").val());
    var secondresult = parseInt($("#score2").val());

    if(firstresult < secondresult) {
      result = '2';
    } else if(firstresult > secondtresult) {
      result ='1';
    } else if (firstresult = secondresult) { 
      result = 'x';       
    } 

    alert(result);     
  });  
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UYmzF/     @answered -  i posted it.  i still need help. im working on it. thank for your answers. i when i press enter i should get 1 or x or 2...

Comment: @jwin27 - There was a typo in `secondresult` variable. I fixed it take a look http://jsfiddle.net/UYmzF/1/

Comment: thx but it does not work correctly: second enter button check the value of first values. so second line is useless. i mean if i press the second enter button it gives the result of first line.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, using `prev`/`next` when referencing an ID is sub-optimal. By nature, an ID has to be unique, so there should not be any "next" or "previous" element with that same name. Because of this, just grab it with a single-select: `$('#elementId')`

Second, I would break every relation down by the most-common element, albeit its own siblings (elements in the same parent tag) or `<tr>` element and find your element that way. Traverse the tree through the element as high as you can stand going (without losing scope). For instance:

From either `.add` or `.minus` you can get the score box in the same row from `siblings()`, for example:

```
$(this).siblings('.score').val();
```

To compare rows of values, take advantage of the `<tr>` tag(s):

```
// .score element in next row
$(this)            // from the button clicked
  .closest('tr')   // move up to the <tr>
  .next()          // on to the next row
  .find('.score'); // then in this row, find the .score element

// .score element in previous row
$(this)
  .closest('tr')
  .prev()          // same as above, just go up a row
  .find('.score');
```

If you still need help, post a jsfiddle.net of what you have and I'm sure we can help you out.